# Notes.app on OS X crashing whenever I make an edit in the iOS app

Tags: macos, applications, notes.app

Notes.app on OS X crashes whenever I make an edit in the iOS app and it syncs back down to my Mac. When it crashes, I just open up the app again, and everything is synced up and works perfectly. The crashing is obviously super annoying, though. Has anyone else seen this problem?

Comment: Any corrupted notes inside your Notes.app?

Comment: Possibly... What might make a note corrupted?

Comment: A crash like that ;) Maybe you can check if one of the notes contain "weird" information or weird characters. -- Do you have many of them? Else you could recreate most of them to check.